# C#: parametrized string with spaces only between "full" parameters?

Tags: c#, string

I want to output a string that welcomes a user to the application. I have the user's first, middle and last name. I would like to write the user's full name, i.e. `"Hello {0} {1} {2}"` with first, middle and last being the parameters. However, If the middle name is empty, I don't want two spaces between the first and the last name, but rather only one space. I can obviously do it with an "if", but is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", first, middle, last).Replace("  "," ")
```

Comment: I like that one the best. I could use "Hello "+your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Hello {0} {1}{3}{2}"
```

where

```
{3} = param1.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "" : " "
```

Comment: this still gives you 2 spaces?

Comment: @Jimmy: the spaces are conditional to the parameter at position {1}.. so no, you don't get 2 spaces if param1 is null or empty.

Comment: @VVS: if {1} is null or empty, then the result is {0}{2}. You should turn one of the {3}'s into a space, i think.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worthwhile to make a `Name` class that has a `Full` property that takes care of that logic (i.e. will print `"John Smith"` if there is no middle name or `"John A. Smith"` if there is).

Then your code would be:

```
var name = new Name(first, middle, last);
var message = string.Format("Hello {0}", name.Full);
```

You could also consider adding `LastFirstMiddle` property (to get a `"Smith, John A."` formatted string) and any other properties that would make sense with the `Name` class.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to put the space into the parameter string.  For example (only first and last name as an example)

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}{1}{2}",
  firstName,
  String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ? String.Empty : " ", 
  lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hello =
    (from name in new[] { "Hello", firstName, middleName, lastName }
     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
     .Aggregate((xs, x) => xs + " " + x);
```

or

```
var hello = string.Join(" ", 
    (from name in new[] { "Hello", firstName, middleName, lastName }
     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
     .ToArray());
```

Comment: If you have a golden hammer, everything looks like a nail, right? :-)

Seriously though, don't you agree that this syntax obfuscates the intention here, rather than keeping it readable?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method in my projects. and it helps alot.

```
public string LogicFullName(string fName)
    {
        string logicName = String.Empty;
        string[] splitFullName = fName.Trim().Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < splitFullName.Length; i++)
        {
            if (logicName == String.Empty && i == 0)
            {
                logicName = splitFullName[i].Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                if (splitFullName[i] != String.Empty)
                    logicName = logicName + " " + splitFullName[i].Trim();
            }
        }
        return logicName;
     }
```